# formatting yyyy/mm/dd in VB Script to Month name and day date

Tags: arrays, vb.net, date, datetime, vbscript

How can you format **yyyy/mm/dd** in VBScript to only Output Month name and day date `'Month Name' 'Day'` eg. **June 6**

Sorry if this is a bad question - new to VBScript. My research has found only super lengthy solutions and just numeric formatting and rearranging, I need **month name**!

Recent attempt (please notice I'm trying to use `(DatePart("m"` but I also need to output the HTML etc I am writing within `<section id='`

```
<%
    today = Date

    firstDay = DateValue("2015-05-10")
    lastDay  = DateValue("2015-06-08")
    d = firstDay
    While d <= lastDay
      If d = today Then
        response.write "today"
      Else
        response.write(DatePart("m","<section id='day_"& d &"' class='calSquare  " & time &"'><article class='dateImage' style='background-image: url(images/Calendar_Thumbnails/Day_"&d&".jpg)'></article></article><article class='dateTitle'> "&d&suffix&"</article></section>"))      
        End If
      d = d + 1
    Wend

    <!--response.write(products(0))-->
%>
```

The above failed; also tried MonthName but couldn't use properly maintaining the html I'm populating.. **Any suggestions as to how to output MonthName and then just numeric day date, maintaining my HTML I am populating dynamically as seen in above code?**

Comment: What is the expected output? And why is the second parameter of `DatePart` an HTML string?

Comment: Because it creates unique calendar element plus styles for each date area. The output needs to literally be 'The Month Name' like: 'May or June' and then 'numeric date': So, if it's June 4. June 4 would work. May 30. May 30 would work.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you want to output HTML, but the second parameter of `DatePart` is **the date value** whose day/month/year you want to get, not the output string. Your actual code is telling vbscript "get me the month from `<section id='day_"& d &"' class='calSquare  " & time &"'><article class='dateImage' style='background-image: url(images/Calendar_Thumbnails/Day_"&d&".jpg)'></article></article><article class='dateTitle'> "&d&suffix&"</article></section>"))`, wich is not a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MONTHNAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxbsw165%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function.  It takes a integer not a date so you could do something like the following.

```
MONTHNAME(MONTH("1/12/2015")) & " " & DAY("1/12/2015")
```

Output:

```
January 12
```

Comment: So I replace your code with DateValue? Those two lines with your 1?

Comment: I would think that you would just change how your concatenating the HTML string you're trying to output.  Something like    `response.write(MONTHNAME(MONTH(today)),"<section id='day_"& DAY(TODAY) &"' class='calSquare  " & time &"'><article class='dateImage' style='background-image: url(images/Calendar_Thumbnails/Day_"&d&".jpg)'></article></article><article class='dateTitle'> "&d&suffix&"</article></section>"))`

Comment: And test result = blank white page =/ why would you do that to me, man?

Comment: Is "today" your variable that contains the date you want to display and can you confirm that it's getting populated?

Comment: It works before attempt at formatting; EG, this runs -- >  response.write("<section id='day_"& d &"' class='calSquare  " & time &"'><article class='dateImage' style='background-image: url(images/Calendar_Thumbnails/Day_"&d&".jpg)'></article></article><article class='dateTitle'> "&d&suffix&"</article></section>")

Comment: It outputs dates between range numerically. But I need the MonthName

Comment: So, can't you wrap MONTHNAME around whatever element is producing the numeric output?

Comment: You would think and I would think; but just doesn't work for me!

Comment: Can you give us an example of the desired HTML output with both day and month name? Not the `response.write` parameter, not the code that you're getting with your actual code; the final HTML code you want to get in your web page.

Comment: Basically a div for each calendar day in date range and at the bottom 'May 6th' but the 'th' is a luxury.  Showing all in date range. May 10th, May 11, May 12th - all the way to June 8th. In div boxes, with that date format at the bottom. Now it's just outputting in this format: 5/11/2015. Today's date must be detected as class="today" would be appended to that calendar day!!!!!

Answer (score -2):

Use d.month to get the month and do.year to get the year. Convert the d.month to month name by creating a function to do so

Comment: This would work better as a comment.. Thanks for the elaborate answer, John.